# How to calculate mean of array with type numpy64float?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very big cycle in which I need to calculate mean. In this cycle I generate 1000 possible `oddsratio`. Just look at the end of my code:

```
oddsratio=(cross_tab[1][1]*cross_tab[0][0])/(cross_tab[1][0]*cross_tab[0][1])
lst = [oddsratio]
np_lst = np.array(oddsratio)
new_array = np_lst.astype(type('float', (float,), {}))
mean_arr = np.mean(new_array)
print(sum(new_array)/len(new_array))
```

the output (many numbers) of oddsratio is numpyfloat64 and I got error using `np.mean()` or `statistics.mean()`
I tried to convert it in np.array, but got error again: `'float' object is not iterable` If i just run `print(mean_arr)` it gives me all numbers of `oddsratio`

Initially, I tried to convert in list, but output created for every value in list with additional '[]', for example I had `lst = [[0.9][0.7][0.6]....]`. I tried to remove inner list, but it does not work also.

[Output of oddsrato](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyGLX.png)

I never worked with numpy previously,and the mistake is not understandable for me. Please could anybody give me advice how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have example values of `oddsratio`? And do you want to get the mean of `oddsratio`?

Comment: @cmbfast I put in my question the screenshot of output of oddsratio. And yes, I tried to calculate mean of oddsratio

Comment: Show the full error message

Comment: Is tis the error line? ` np_lst.astype(type('float', (float,), {}))`. what's that `type` call suposed to do?

Comment: No, this line is part of code. If I tried calculate mean of ```oddsrato```, I got error where I can not calculate mean with numpy64float, this line makes type numpy float

Answer (score 1):

the [numpy reference for np.mean](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) says that `np.mean` return value is an `ndarray`, but if you don't specify the `axis` argument it will return a single float. that's why `sum(mean_arr)` throws a `TypeError` (object not iterable).

i don't understand when you say that `print(mean_arr)` gives you all numbers of `oddsratio`: the screen you  posted shows `print(oddsratio)`. `mean_arr` is just a float. either you're always printing `oddratio`, or you're not showing us the entirety of your code.

Comment: I tried with axis ```np.mean(new_array,axis=0)``` and I got the same results - all values. I did not show the output of ```mean_arr```, because there is no difference between output with ```print(oddsratio```

Comment: @Greck9 what is the shape of cross_tab?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call mean() on your array?

```
np_lst.mean()
```

Comment: I tried ```print(np_lst(mean))``` but I got the same output - all numbers of oddsratio, not mean between them

Comment: Specifically try what I suggested, `np_lst.mean()`.
Assuming np_lst is the numpy array of numbers, that will give you a single mean value output.

`np_lst` is not a function, so `np_lst(mean)` will not work.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I tried your code ```np_lst.mean()``` and it gives me all numbers. Yes, you are right, ```np_lst(mean)``` does not give anything, because it is not a function

Comment: What do you get if you print out the type of np_lst?
`type(np_list)`

Comment: a lot of ```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>```, as i understood this type for every value. It does not read it a whole list

Comment: Okay.. so if you print out the type of `oddsratio[0]`, you don't get a numpy float but an ndarray?